# How can I use VLC, Mplayer or ffplay in Ubuntu Touch/Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, vlc, mplayer, mir

I've installed them on Ubuntu Touch/phone - but when I start them in an terminal, Vlc, Mplayer will only play the video in ascii-mode, and ffplay complains that it could not intialize SDL.  I guess they can't find any display outputs? Is this because Ubuntu Touch is using Mir instead of X?
What could be done to play a video from the terminal in Ubuntu Touch?

Comment: You are correct that there is no X server on the phone.  Packages that depend on X can theoretically be installed yet will fail to function.